# preventDefault não funciona

Tags: javascript

No seguinte `form`:

```
<form id="form_id" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="valida_form()">
```

tenho uma função que verifica se há espaços em branco:

```
function valida_form(evt)
{   Array.from(document.getElementById("form_id")).forEach(function(element,index)
    {   if(element.value === "")
        {   form_err++;
        }
    });
    if(form_err > 0)
    {   alert("Há erros:"+form_err);
        evt.preventDefault();
    }else
    {   alert("Sem erro"+form_err);
    }
}
```

entretanto o `form`continua sendo enviado.

Estou aprendendo a passagem de argumentos, e `callbacks` então se o erro for algo relacionado, agradeço a explicação.

Comment: Acho que está faltando passar o escopo aqui `valida_form(this)` e `alert` é bloqueante, poderia previnir o evento padrão dele ou trocar por `console`

Comment: se diz na tag do form, se for eu tentei..?

Comment: Isso mesmo @MagicHat, `onsubmit="valida_form(this)"`

Comment: Então eu tentei isso tmb... ele alerta o erro e talz, mas envia o form,,

Comment: pra teste, coloque o `evt.preventDefault()` na primeira linha do corpo da função

Comment: seguinte ele num tá reconhecendo o elemento do `preventDefaut`...ele diz: `evt.preventDefault is not a function`...isso deixando o método onde está igual no exemplo da pergunta

Comment: Por algum motivo na tag ele não "reconhece" o `preventDefault`, talvez por ser uma função invocada ou por processar o submit de forma diferente, assim funciona, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/xvf80gy0/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `preventDefault` não funciona quando o event listener é definido inline no HTML (`onsubmit="..."`). Use `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById('form_id').addEventListener('submit', valida_form, false);
```

Quando você usa inline, a função precisa retornar `false` para cancelar a operação padrão. E o handler inline precisa retornar o resultado da função: `onsubmit="return funcao()"`. Existe ainda a possibilidade de se passar um objeto `event` global na chamada, como o Anderson Carlos Woss comentou abaixo. Porém isso não é padrão e não pode não funcionar em todos os browsers. O mais recomendado é usar `addEventListener` mesmo.

Comment: Não funciona porque o evento não é passado por parâmetro na chamada, mas se passá-lo funcionaria, certo? Por exemplo: `onsubmit="valida_form(event)"`, ou, dentro da função verificar a existência do evento com `if (!evt) evt = window.event`.

Comment: Funcionou com addEventListener... Agora para chamar ela inline, chamei de tudo quanto é nome..."evt,e,event, this,(fdp)"...num foi naum

Comment: Não tenho certeza se funcionaria, preciso testar. A existência de event global não é padrão, melhor evitar.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Tem razão, funciona sim se a global `event` estiver disponível. No Chrome pelo menos.

Comment: Exatamente. Eu fiz os testes e funcionou, mas não achei documentação que comprovasse um comportamento padrão nisso. O ideal é utilizar o `addEventListener` que é certo a passagem do evento.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Mencionei isso na resposta. Testei agora em Chrome, FF e Safari, os 3 no OSX, versões atuais, e funcionou em todos o `event` global. Antigamente não funcionava no FF, certeza. Fica aqui [um teste](https://jsfiddle.net/d8d5e2yz/) para futuras verificações.